# Get an advanced custom field after post publish

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

After I publish a post I want to get a custom field from the plugin advanced custom fields and store it inside a database. tried this:

```
    function call_after_post_publish($post_id, $post) {


    $tcParentTitle = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $tcChildTitle  = get_field( 'funcion_1_titulo_tc', $post_id ); 





    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'link',
        array(
            'parent_title' => $tcParentTitle,
            'title'    => $tcChildTitle,
            'parent_id'    => $post_id,


        ),
        array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%d'


        )   
    );
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'call_after_post_publish', 10, 2 );
```

This doesn't seem to work because I think the function get_field() works only after the post is created. Is there other way I can get the custom field value?

Comment: Look in `$_POST` for data or use the `acf/save_post` action instead.

Comment: The hook `publish_post`  is fired before `save_post` that's used by ACF. So it's better to hook into `save_post` with higher priority value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `wp_insert_post` hook to make sure that everything is processed before you hook in.

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_wp_insert_post_cb', 10, 2 );
function my_wp_insert_post_cb( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```